# Handling a large local database in a chrome extension

Tags: database, chrome

I'm creating a chrome extension which needs a large local database.
After researching my options, I figured my best bet is probably to use the `chrome.storage.local` API and give my extension the `unlimitedStorage` permission.

As far as I understand, this API lets me get and set individual objects referenced by a key.

I need to maintain several lists of items (exact number to be determined, but probably around 10). The most common operation will be retrieving and setting a single item from one of those lists, although I also need to retrieve all items from a particular list (the number of items in a list may grow to around 10,000).

Now my issue is the following: if I were to save each list under a different key, then I'd need to retrieve the whole list and save the whole list again just to modify a single item. If I saved each list item under a different key, all items from different lists would be mixed together and I'd need to retrieve the whole database to find all the items of a specific list.

Is there a solution I'm missing which solves both problems at once? (i.e. being able to easily retrieve all items from a list and being able to modify only a particular item from a list)

Comment: Added some estimates.

Comment: A straightforward solution to... what problem, exactly?

Comment: Edited last paragraph in hope that it is more clear.

Comment: Have you looked into [IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb)?

Comment: What about saving each item under a different key, but use keys which are a combination of a list number and an item number? That way, you could still identify all elements of one list, without mixing them up with other elements. Of course, to retrieve all items of one list, you will still need one API call per item, but did you actually measure if that is a bottleneck, or if it is fast enough for your case?

Comment: @EricKing Somehow I didn't stumble upon IndexedDB. It looks like a way better option and solves pretty much all my problems. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DocBrown I thought of that, but didn't really like the solution. I haven't measured if it is the bottleneck since the program is still very early in development. However, since this is a side-project I'm doing in my free time (to be of use, but also to learn), I'm trying to make the code as good as I can, even though I definitely don't need to.